# Creation of one column matrix

Tags: matrix

I want to create an one column matrix with the 1st element to be -1, and all the other elements to be zero. However, I want to be able to make a  matrix of this kind with arbitrary dimension, that is, an arbitrary number of rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
makeArray[n_Integer] := 
  Module[{a = ConstantArray[{0}, n]}, a[[1, 1]] = -1; a]

makeArray[4]
```

> {{-1}, {0}, {0}, {0}}

There almost certainly more elegant ways to doing this, but this is the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: Thanks your answer, it was very helpful!

Comment: I'm glad to help, but if you *really* like my answer, click on the accept button (check mark on the left of this answer).

Comment: @m_goldberg I always encourage users to **wait longer before accepting an answer** as I'm sure you've read before.  It certainly doesn't hurt to point out that functionality as it's not entirely obvious, but unless you have strong feelings to the contrary I think it best *not* to encourage fast Accepts.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I understand what you are saying and agree that I was hasty here. I will be more careful not to discourage potential additional answers in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
coln[n_] := Join[{{-1}}, Table[{0}, {i, n}]];
(*n is the dimension*)
coln[5]
```

gives you `{{-1}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}`

If you want to make a `Column` or `Matrix` with only one finite element (say x) at a position (say i for a column or i,j for a matrix) the `KroneckerDelta` will be a better option.

```
col[x_, i_, n_] := Table[{x KroneckerDelta[i, j]}, {j, n}]; 
row[x_, i_, n_] := Table[x KroneckerDelta[i, j], {j, n}];
mat[x_, i_, j_, n_] := Table[x KroneckerDelta[i, p] KroneckerDelta[j, q], {p, n}, {q, n}];
```

then

```
mat[0.5,2,2,3]
```

will give you a matrix with 0.5 at (2,2) and zero everywhere else. Same for column and row.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use sparse matrix to press in particular indices.Check this following example,

```
Normal[SparseArray[{1 -> -1}, RandomInteger[{2, 9}]]]
```

Output:`{-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

You can put it in function to take it to more than 9 as number of rows.

**Edit**: As pointed out the snippet above will produce one row,so this minor improvisation will do it.

```
Normal[{SparseArray[{1 -> -1}, RandomInteger[{2, 9}]]}] // Transpose
```

Output:`{{-1}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}`

Comment: SparseArray seems a nice way to go, but this produces a row vector, not a one-column, 2D matrix

Comment: You can use this: `Normal[SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> -1}, {10, 1}]]` for 10 elements.

Answer (score 4):

```
Transpose@DiagonalMatrix[{-1}, 0, {1, 5}]
```

=> {{-1}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}

**Edit**

```
ArrayFlatten@{{-1}, {ConstantArray[{0}, 4]}}
```

=> {{-1}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

Probably the most transparent and concise version is this:

```
-Thread[{UnitVector[5, 1]}]

(* ==> {{-1}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}} *)
```

The first argument of [UnitVector](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitVector.html) is the dimension, and the second argument is the position where the `1` appears. Obviously, this is exactly the kind of problem `UnitVector` was made for.

**End Edit**

Another possibility:

```
-{KroneckerDelta[1, #]} & /@ Range[5]

(* ==> {{-1}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}} *)
```

This has the advantage of being easily generalized to setting any other element to `-1`. For example, to do it with the third element:

```
-{KroneckerDelta[3, #]} & /@ Range[5]

(* ==> {{0}, {0}, {-1}, {0}, {0}} *)
```

Comment: Very nice.  I was (also) not aware of you usage of **Thread**. (I have almost always used **Transpose** for this purpose).  `Thread@DiagonalMatrix[{-1}, 0, {1, 5}]` == 
 `Transpose@
  DiagonalMatrix[{-1}, 
   0, {1, 5}]` == `-Thread[{UnitVector[5, 
     1]}]` == `-Transpose@{UnitVector[5, 1]}`